# How old was Bagoas when he met Alexander the Great?

Tags: alexander-the-great, macedon, ancient-iran

And what was the ethnicity of Bagoas? As I know, there were many different people's and tribes, that populates Achaemenian Empire. And also there was extended slave trade with foreign nations.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786) Who was Bagoas? Where is it attested that he met Alexander?  Where have you looked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to know because there are no records of his birthdate.

Answer (score 2):

Bagoas was Persian as the name is of Persian origin. He was, to quote Curtius, "in the very flower of his youth" when he first met Alexander. That seems to me to be 16-18 years old.

Comment: I think the best you can say is that he was likely to be Persian because that's were that name originates, it's not definitive proof.